# Most efficient way to fill DataGrid with DbSet

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I a WPF DataGrid that I fill with a DbSet with `ToList()`. I'm looking for a way to speed this up.

```
using MyNameSpace.Data.DataModels;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyNameSpace.Data
{
    public class DB: DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options_builder) {
            options_builder.UseSqlServer("Server=server;Database=database;TrustServerCertificate=true;Integrated Security=true");

        }

        public DbSet<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The main window looks like this:

```
using MyNameSpace.Data;
using MyNameSpace.Data.DataModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<Projects> projects = new List<Projects>();
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RetrieveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            GetProjects();
        }

        public void GetProjects() {
            var db = new DB();
            projects = db.Projects.ToList();
            ProjectsDatagrid.ItemsSource = projects;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to get rid of the `ToList`. Is there a way to stream values to the datagrid so as to avoid first fitting everything in a list?

Comment: `DataGrid.ItemsSource` is of type `IEnumerable`, so you could simply point this to your Projects `DbSet` to avoid explicit `List` creation.

Comment: Neither DataGrid nor DbSet are data containers. A DbSet is a repository which you use to load data from a database. A DataGrid is a UI element that displays data. The efficient way is to only display what's needed, using that control's binding and data virtualization (if available)

Comment: The other option is to use paging so you only have to display one page of data at a time. This may be more friendly to end users than an infinitely scrolling grid of thousands of items, allowing them to move to specific pages. DataGrid is relatively basic and doesn't offer either option out of the box.

Comment: If I use ``ProjectsDatagrid.ItemsSource = db.Projects.Local.ToObservableCollection();``, the screen remains empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm looking for a way to display everything the query returns. If I have to get rid of this DataGrid, why not but what should I use instead?

Comment: Seeing "ButtonClick" in teh same code as "new DbContext".... and binding directly to the dbcontext.  i would suggest internet search for "dotnet core 3 layer application".   you can read about this ("buffering and streaming").... but this article is not a substitute for layering your app.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#buffering-and-streaming

Comment: @granadaCoder My question already mentioned streaming values because I already saw this article. I don't understand both your comment and how to do that.